# Is it possible to add Lighting Web Component in the Visual force Page?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components

Create one Web Component and want to that in VF page, Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, it is possible for now Spring 19 only by means of lightning aura components.

1. Create `LWC`
2. Create `aura` component, that includes `LWC` from step 1 [see doc how it works](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.interop_aura_composition)
3. Using [lightning out for visualfroce](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/02/lightning-components-visualforce-lightning.html) display `aura` component from step 2

Comment: Thank you Oleksandr Berehovskyi

Answer (score 0):

There are three steps to add Aura components to a Visualforce page.

- Add the Lightning Components for `Visualforce` JavaScript library to your Visualforce page using the `<apex:includeLightning/>` component.
- Create and reference a Lightning app that declares your component dependencies.
- Write a `JavaScript` function that creates the component on the page using `$Lightning.createComponent()`.

Here is example:

Aura App

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp"> 
    <aura:dependency resource="lightning:button"/>
</aura:application>
```

Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeLightning />

    <div id="lightning" />

    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:AuraAppName", function() {});
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Note: using this you can also include `LWC` component in `visualforce` page.